# Mercurial correct way to return to default branch

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We develop new modules for our application on separate branches. When they have been tested they are merged into the default branch. When we need to make changes to a module we reopen the branch, make the changes, test and finally merge into the default branch again.

Occasionally whilst updating a module we identify bugs within our core code. Often we will fix the bug and then commit the changes back to the default branch. However, because we are in the module branch, we have to reopen "default".

This did not have the desired effect as we ended up with 2 default branches.

So what is the correct way to commit to "default" when you are within another branch without losing the changes? (preferably using TortoiseHg).

Below is a screenshot of the TortoiseHg dialog where I select the "default" branch, followed by what happens to the graph.

[image: opening default branch]

Comment: What do you mean by "reopen default"?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to better explain.

Comment: @Ben looking at your screenshot, I really don't understand your workflow... Why are there commits after the selected one ? If you're working in branches for the new modules, the bugfix commit should be the **last one on the default branch**. Can you please describe your workflow better with each steps involved in the process (branch creation for new module, what you do for bugfixing, etc). BTW, have you tried my solution ? it should be fairly easy to "translate" for TortoiseHG, the command have the exact same name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `hg update default`
2. Do the changes
3. `hg commit`
4. `hg update modulebranch`

If you described your workflow correctly, this should work without creating any new head or whatsoever.

If you need to retrieve the changes in your module branch, you can add `hg merge default` as a fifth step.

If you have uncommited changes in your repository and don't want to commit them before updating to default, you can use the [Shelve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension) for example, or simply save the content of `hg diff` to a file that you will later reapply with `hg patch`.

Comment: thanks. Any idea why I would get duplicate "default" branches as indicated in the screenshot?

Comment: @Ben look at my comment to your question, I think something is flawed in your workflow, what you're describing shouldn't happened if you do things correctly. The bugfix commit should be the last on the default branch and not lost somewhere in the "middle" of the branch

Comment: as you say, this is probably an issue with my workflow (I should switch back to the default branch before making the fix). However, it doesn't explain why when committing to the default branch it actually created a new default branch that I then had to merge with the other.

Comment: It all depends on what is the current revision when you do your commit. If the parent of the commit is not the HEAD of the branch, a new HEAD will be created. Just update to the HEAD before committing and this will solve your issue.

Comment: I can't find a way of doing this through the Workbench UI so I had to use the terminal. Thank you!